# Anyone Aware of a Way to Identify OEM vs ISV Applications on AppExchange?

Tags: appexchange, isv, partner, oem

Looking for a way, which would have to be creative since none exist directly, to identify OEM apps on the AppExchange. We are one ourselves so I'd like to see which apps can be installed by non-Salesforce customers (OEM) vs the alternative.

I do not think there is a way to do this but asking the experts.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anyway to identify OEM apps. An admin of an OEM org can install any app from the Appexchange, there are no restrictions. The only restrictions is whether the OEM ISV will allow an install to take place. Many OEM apps can now be licensed as ISVForce apps as well. The other complication is that if an Admin on an OEM only org does install another appexchange they maybe be breaching their licensing agreement with the ISV partner.